# update Chart Js with new data onclick button

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am sending a POST request to a php file to fetch new data to update my chart, although I am getting the data I needed my chart wont be updated, I can't see where the problem is in my code.

```js
function LoadResultOnClickButton()
{

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'mydata.php',
    data: {type: 'search'},
    success: function(data){
        var chart = new Chartist.Pie('.ct-chart-category', 
        {
              
              series: data},
              
                {
  
                    donut: true,
                    showLabel: false,
                    donutWidth: 40

                }
              
              );
        }
});

}
```

```css
My test data (php file)

<?php

$type=$_POST['type'];
if ($type=="search")
{

    $Labels = array();
    $series = array();
    $Labels = ['success','Error','Disabled'];
    $series = [40,20,40];

    $Labels_Json = json_encode($Labels);
    $Data_Json = json_encode($series, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    echo $Data_Json;
}
else
{
    
  $Labels = array();
  $series = array();
  $Labels = ['success','Error','Disabled'];
  $series = [75,20,5];

  $Labels_Json = json_encode($Labels);
  $Data_Json = json_encode($series, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    echo $Data_Json;
}

    

?>
```

```html
My HTML code :

<div id="myChart" class="ct-chart-category ct-golden-section" style="height: 315px;"></div>
<a href="#" id="filtrebtn" onclick="LoadResultOnClickButton();" class="btn btn-rounded btn-light">filtrebtn</a></div>
```

I'm sorry if my explanation is hard to understand; it was difficult for me to explain. Please ask me for any clarification you need.

Best regards